# what does ablkcipher_request_set_callback do?

Tags: c, linux, api, linux-kernel

I saw codes after codes online, but hardly any clear and direct descriptions on what `ablkcipher_request_set_callback()` does.

In `include/linux/crypto.h`, there is zero comments. Can anyone give any insights and how to use this function?

Comment: Can someone answer the question instead of doing non-constructive markdowns? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: What have you got so far? What is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function in Linux crypto framework.

The simple theory is:

> Linux crypto framework assume there might be a HW chip in your
>   machine, which could do cryption / decryption work, like AES, DES.
>
> So it construct a request to this HW chip. And the chip would do its
>   work in parallel with your CPU.
>
> After HW chip is done with the request, it notify your CPU about the
>   complete event, ususally by IRQ.
>
> Then the IRQ handler (well, actually bottom half for most of time)
>   would execute the callback function you specify in the request.
>
> So: `ablkcipher_request_set_callback()` is to set the callback function
>   of encrypt / decrypt request.

A real example is like:

> Suppose you are running IPsec protocol. It would do the following
>   logic:
>
> Construct a packet encrypt request, with callback function "when
>   encryption done, please transmit this packet out".
>
> Submit the encryption request to HW chip driver, and further to HW
>   chip.
>
> After HW chip done with encryption of this packet,  HW chip driver
>   would run this callback function "transmit this encrypted packet out".

=======================================================================

IPsec uses
       aead_givcrypt_set_callback()

not
       ablkcipher_request_set_callback()

"ablkcipher" means a "block cipher" (like AES), "a" standards for "asynchronous" ( run in parralel with CPU).

"aead" could be considered  as combined algorithm of ( "ablkcipher" + compute a hash value ). In IPsec case,  the hash value is the packet CRC.

Add the IPSec code fragment:    # in $(kernel)/net/ipv4/esp4.c

static int esp_output(struct xfrm_state *x, struct sk_buff *skb)

```
     /* set the callback esp_output_done(), which would essentially call
      *     dev_queue_xmit()     # transmit the encrypted packet out
      */
    aead_givcrypt_set_callback(req, 0, esp_output_done, skb)

    /*
     * sumbit the request to Linux crypto framework, which internally would forward
     * the request to a HW chip driver.
     *
     * The HW chip driver accept the request, and return EINPROGRESS indicating
     * the request is being handled in progress or queued for handling.
     *
     * After HW chip done with encryption, request callback esp_output_done() is 
     * called
     */
    err = crypto_aead_givencrypt(req);
if (err == -EINPROGRESS)
    goto error;
```

--- Well, to much detail not covered, and like you said, "undocumenting" causes a lot of trouble to us.

Comment: This is very good explanation. Could you give some code sample, eg. of a simple AES with comments of the process? It would really complete the picture.

Comment: I am very very impressed with this explanation. If only you are the one in-charge, Linux would be so much better.

+1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a kernel header file (as are all the headers in `/include/linux` so it's not really intended for use in a normal application. The assumption is that if you are working with the kernel (such as writing a device driver), then you should read the source to get a better understanding of what is doing.

Anything that you are supposed to use in applications will not be in the linux directory and will have a man page explaining what it does and how to use it.

There is some [documentation here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.13.3/Documentation/crypto/api-intro.txt), but it doesn't include the function you are asking about.

Comment: The source has no comments and with poor variable naming. The way things are mapped is non-intuitive. How is this being used? And what does it really actually do? Why is there no description for what it really does? I had asked several people, no one can answer me. Why is this so obscure? The web is filled with codes with no **direct** descriptions. Why is it even so hard to just tell what it does?

+1 for your help, jamesj.

Comment: @Babbit I agree. Unfortunately that's how it goes with kernel development in my experience. You learn how it works by reading and debugging the code. Makes for a steep learning curve.

Comment: It's a practical waste of life. I am surprise why hardly people want to change this kind of danger wasteful mindset. 1000s of hours around the world wasted on this undocumented junk, making us 'monkeys trying to put toothpaste back in the paste tube'. It is absolutely irresponsible. I always have a step-by-step guide, and correct in any feedback of ambiguity. No guessing, no trial and error. Life is too short for dumb work like that. There has to be a better way - we engineer the world. 

I will find a way.